# Meta tag description is not working?

Tags: html

I inserted html meta tag to display a meta text when person search on Google about my website.

The way I set meta tag description :

I go through some research regarding this but found something like this : 
google is not considering meta description tag in its algorithm since 2009

Is there another way to implement meta description which will work or support by google algorithm? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google doesn't support the meta description tag in the sense of ranking your website. They may however use your description tag to provide a description of your website.

If you just changed your meta description tag, please give Google some time to come back and crawl your website again.

Comment: It is working it takes 1 day to reflect change thanks @Adherence

Answer (score 2):

You can set the meta tag as follows,

```
<meta name="description" content="A description of the page" />
```

This tag provides a short description of the page. In some situations this description is used as a part of the snippet shown in the search results.

Also refer the following link,
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, [Google as of 2009](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) no longer uses meta tag **keywords** (not *description*) for its search algorithms. It is still useful though; Baidu is one of many engines that still indexes meta tags. However, you were talking about meta tag *description*. The instruction provided by Google on this reads as such (my emphasis below):

> The description attribute within the  tag is a good way to provide a concise, human-readable summary of each page’s content. *Google will sometimes use the meta description of a page in search results snippets, if we think it gives users a more accurate description than would be possible purely from the on-page content.* Accurate meta descriptions can help improve your clickthrough; here are some guidelines for properly using the meta description. [From: Review your page titles and snippets](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?visit_id=1-636118506904518098-3622510368&rd=1)

It would seem that Google for some reason have decided that your meta tag description is not of adequate help to the user. If you provided your description and a link to the site, it would be easier to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about this stuff but I seems like seo
So once you set the google crawler it starts with taking a snapshot of your complete code and meta tags are ignored just because 1) they dont support it anymore 2) google had this problem because they have to make a negative impression on black hat seo techniques

My advice for you would be to go through some articles before you consider anything to be working

And by the way keyword tree that is used at the time you make a search query at google is only build from the static content of your website and nothing else